# Which of the following is better in terms of performance and speed?

Tags: 7, views, database

1. I am creating a view and then using views_get_view_result() function to get the query and print a csv file 
   or
2. Creating a query using db_select and then using it to  print the csv.
   Which of the above would give me quicker results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[views_get_view_result()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_get_view_result/7) will be slower as compared to the `db_query` as the `views_get_view_result()` calls all the views api functions to get the result but it is the recommended method to get result.

However if your query result changes rarely than you may cache the result and it would be better in terms of performance, Views already has built-in Views has caching system and can be configured in your view, or otherwise you can cache the `db_query` result as well.

References of caching:

- [cache_get()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!cache.inc/function/calls/cache_get/7)
- [variable_initialize()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/variable_initialize/7)

Answer (score 3):

db_select would give quicker results as it doesn't invoke the entire Views API to get that database result set. However, Views will give you the benefit of a highly configurable user interface to adjust your query which may save on development time.